# How to emit individually delayed elements to Sink in Java Reactor (Webflux)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, scheduling

I'd like to emit **individually delayed** elements (each element with its own delay, different from each other) into a [sink](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Sinks.Many.html), to which many other clients are subscribed via a `Flux`.

I had the idea of using something like this:

```java
Sinks.Many<MyElement> sink = Sinks.many()
    .replay()
    .limit(Duration.ZERO);
sink.asFlux().
    .... processing
    .subscribe();
```

And then other threads emit into the sink:

```java
sink.tryEmitNext(newElement);
```

I would like to reach the effect that each element is emitted with its own individual delay, something like the imaginary code here:

```java
sink.tryEmitNextPostponed(newElement, Duration.of(...));
```

By **delayed** I mean delayed from the time of inserting into the sink, not delayed from each other. So maybe rather "postponed emit".

I know I can make the `Flux` delay emitting each element with [Flux.delayElements(Duration)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#delayElements-java.time.Duration-), but then the delay is always the same and the elements cannot "overtake in the queue".

The motivation behind is to implement a flux of "scheduled tasks" to be processed reactively.

Comment: This sounds a lot like sleep sort. Would you be open to a solution that arranges the elements in the preferred order but does not involve any delays? If not you could try using the `Flux.delayElements` method inside a `flatMap` so that the delays start at the same time but differ for each element.

Comment: you're already calling `tryEmitNext` from different threads. What prevents you from scheduling these `tryEmitNext` calls yourself with the desired delays? NB: make sure to check the returned `EmitResult` to look out for things like the Sink having been terminated, etc...

Comment: @Khepu The delays are crucial. For the rest of your comment I am not exactly sure what you mean.

Comment: @SimonBaslé There might be about 10,000 emitters. Is it OK to have 10,000 scheduled tasks? Just because of that I wanted to use `Flux` so I am not blocking.

Comment: It _should_ be ok. Vanilla Reactor `Schedulers` are backed by `ScheduledExecutorServices` from the JVM anyway. Alternatives I can think of are A) hashed wheel timers (but I don't have an implementation handy) or B) use an MPSC queue and a single Thread that polls the queue

Comment: @SimonBaslé Would you consider to turn your comment into an answer (and elaborate it a little bit :) )? Especially your point B) - that's exactly **how** we want to implement a kind of MPSC queue with delayed elements :) And the funny thing is that the `Flux` processing contains **re-inserting** elements back to the sink if some conditions were valid.

Comment: actually, I'd like to backtrack on that B alternative which has a limitation in that `tryEmitNext` failure conditions are harder to deal with. the queue idea would work but it could also lead to a situation where nothing restarts the draining of the queue in case it was interrupted due to backpressure. it heavily depends on how the data is generated and how critical things like not blocking generating threads or respecting backpressure are